# Is there a way to read one document at a time using react?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently using this hook:

```
const [Resources, ResourcesLoading] = useCollectionData(collection(firestore, "my-collection"));
```

however, I have around 1000 documents in there, is there a way to read one document at a time with firebase? I don't want to reach the end of the free tier. I need all the ID's or to have some sort of way to get one document at a time, something like a `requestNextDocument()` function or hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to perform a query without fetching all of the documents at once is to use [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query).  You can use `limit(1)` if you want to make a decision about each document before fetching the next one.

Comment: In [this document](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/blob/master/firestore/README.md#usecollectiondata), you can find complementary, useful information related to React Firebase Hooks - Cloud Firestore.